# Adverbe ou déterminant ?

Tags: adverbes, déterminants

Dans la citation suivante, d'Emile Zola, on me dit que le mot **toute** a valeur d'adverbe. Or, ce mot ne me semble pas invariable. A tout prendre, j'aurais opté pour une valeur de déterminant. Pouvez-vous m'expliquer mon erreur ?

> D’habitude, après le déjeuner, on se rendait au bout du parterre, sur une terrasse qui dominait la plaine. Le dimanche, l’après-midi fut d’une douceur exquise. On avait craint de la pluie, vers dix heures ; mais le ciel, sans se découvrir, s’était comme fondu en un brouillard laiteux, en une poussière lumineuse, **toute** blonde de soleil.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deux problèmes distincts :

1. l'adverbe *tout* synonyme de *très/vraiment* n'est pas invariable, il s'accorde en genre et en nombre devant les féminins qui ne font pas liaison (≃commençant par des consonnes)
   *cette rue est toute/très cabossée*
   *ces chemins sont tout/très cabossés*
2. le *tout* de cet exemple est ambigu entre le synonyme de *très* (cf 1.) et le [quantificateur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantificateur_%28grammaire%29) qui s'accorde en genre et en nombre dans tous les contextes
   *ils s'étaient fondus en nuages lumineux, tout/tous blonds de soleil*

   - tout => vraiment blonds de soleil
   - tous => chacun d'eux, blond de soleil

Comment: Et donc *une petite fille toute blonde* et *des petites filles toute (!) blondes*?

Comment: @Arthur => Non. Dans les deux cas (adverbe intensif et quantifieur), il y a accord. Le contraste se manifeste pour les masculins pluriels ou pour les féminins qui déclenchent la liaison : des petites filles **tout** étourdies *vs* des petites filles **toutes** étourdies ; des garçons **tout** calmes *vs* des garçons **tous** calmes.